# New url with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm learning Ajax and I don't understand how to do something:

I have a form that, when submitting the form, the page should not reload. I've seen many examples on how to do this, but they all give a visual response in HTML. Is it possible to give a new PHP url as a response. For example if I had index.php before, after submitting the from (without reloading the page) I would have index.php?name=Alex

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want your submit to refresh the page, you should use:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

And return the click as false.
Example:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            name: 'alex' // input value
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
    return false;  // stop the actual form post !important!
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code by modifying it appropriately with the necessary data, but it does not seem to work. The page is reloaded anyway.  Question. Should the submit button have a function for submitting the form, e.g. <input type="submit">, or should it be a button without a submit function like <p>send</p>? Thank you

Comment: The submit buttons shouldnt have type submit. So "<button name="submit-button" id="submit-button">submit</button>" should work.